# Form tests: How to submit a collection to an existing form?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, domcrawler

I use two ways to test my forms:

### By using `$form = …->form();`

Then setting the values of the `$form` array (more precisely this is a `\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Form` object):

Full example from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests):

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();

// set some values
$form['name'] = 'Lucas';
$form['form_name[subject]'] = 'Hey there!';

// submit the form
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

### By sending the `POST` data directly:

The previous code doesn't work with [forms which manage collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (relying on fields created by Javascript) because it throws an error if the field doesn't exist. That's why I also use [this other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545534/2257664).

Full example from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client):

```
// Directly submit a form (but using the Crawler is easier!)
$client->request('POST', '/submit', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

This solution is the only way I know to test forms which manage collections with fields added by Javascript (see link to documentation above). But this second solution is harder to use because:

- it doesn't check which fields exist, this is impractical when I have to submit a form with existing fields `and` a collection which relies on fields created dynamically  with Javascript
- it requires to add the form `_token` manually

### My question

Is it possible to use the syntax from the first way to define the existing fields then add new dynamically created fields with the second syntax?

In other words, I would like to have something like this:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();

// set some values for the existing fields
$form['name'] = 'Lucas';
$form['form_name[subject]'] = 'Hey there!';

// submit the form with additional data
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

But I get this error:

> Unreachable field "name"

And `$form->get('name')->setData('Fabien');` triggers the same error.

This example is not perfect because the form has no collection, but it's enough to show you my problem.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this validation when I add some fields to the existing form.

Comment: I think this would help you regarding this issue...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454760/symfony2-test-on-arraycollection-gives-unreachable-field

Comment: @NandaKumar thank you but it's the same syntax than in my question (the *By sending the `POST` data directly:* section).

Comment: Can you please post the html form you render ?

Comment: @NandaKumar: I want to submit values for fields that don't exist, are you sure it will help you to see the form?

Comment: you need to add the dynamic elements to the nodes before you setting them up in the code... Please check this link for reference 
http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html

Comment: @NandaKumar: thanks, so I should use `->addNode(…)` in order to add a node to the form?

Comment: Please check this topic Adding the Content http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values

Comment: There is an on-going discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by calling slightly modified code from the [`submit()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/c8d28b1fa6a1103a8d4ff7f2777eb50419d118cf/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php#L250-L263) method:

```
// Get the form.
$form = $crawler->filter('button')->form();

// Merge existing values with new values.
$values = array_merge_recursive(
    $form->getPhpValues(),
    array(
        // New values.
        'FORM_NAME' => array(
            'COLLECTION_NAME' => array(
                array(
                    'FIELD_NAME_1' => 'a',
                    'FIELD_NAME_2' => '1',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

// Submit the form with the existing and new values.
$crawler = $this->client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values,
    $form->getPhpFiles());
```

The array with the news values in this example correspond to a form where you have a fields with these `name`s:

```
<input type="…" name="FORM_NAME[COLLECTION_NAME][A_NUMBER][FIELD_NAME_1]" />
<input type="…" name="FORM_NAME[COLLECTION_NAME][A_NUMBER][FIELD_NAME_2]" />
```

The number (index) of the fields is irrelevant, PHP will merge the arrays and submit the data, Symfony will transform this data in the corresponding fields.