# How to tick a specific checkbox from a multi-dimensional field in a symfony form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

Given a Type that generate this kind of HTML:

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <input
            type="checkbox" 
            id="app_user_responsibilities_14" 
            name="app_user[responsibilities][]" 
            data-responsibility-description="A description." 
            class="form-check-input" 
            value="14">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="app_user_responsibilities_14">Checkbox label</label>
</div>
```

How can I specifically tick it using the Symfony DOM crawler?

I tried:

```php
    $form->setValues([
        'app_user[username]' => $username,
        'app_user[responsibilities]' => [
            14
        ],
    ]);
```

`14` being the `Responsibility` id and the `value` of the input.

But I got an error when I run the test:

```
1) Tests\App\Controller\UserControllerTest::testCreateUserWithResponsibility14
InvalidArgumentException: Input "app_user[responsibilities][]" cannot take "14" as a value (possible values: 8).
```

Comment: i don't claim to be a symphony expert, but searching using google with keywords `set checkbox symphony dom crawler` yielded this results https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175416/3859027 there is a `->tick()` method and you can even select which specific checkbox.

Comment: even in the documentation, they have https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#forms

Comment: I read the documentation, but thank you.
`$form['niwa_pictbundle_proxytype[chronologyControls]'][0]->tick();` use the index of the input in an array, not the value of the input. In my case, the index is not the same as the value.

Comment: That's why I can't use the tick method. Trust me if I could I would already done it.

Comment: the `->tick` method is already available for use, just use it in conjunction with `->filter` to pinpoint using the actual value, not the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have an index different from the value, I need to use the [disableValidation](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.html#method_disableValidation) function in options :

```php
$form->disableValidation()
    ->setValues([
        'app_user[username]' => $username,
        'app_user[responsibilities]' => [
            14,
    ],
]);
```